# Do I need to use methods=['GET', 'POST'] in @app.route()?

Tags: python, flask

My Forms send the age parameter via `GET`, and it worked with just this:

```
@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
  age = request.args['age']
```

I did not bother with

```
@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Does it matter?

Comment: It matters if you want to _specify_ the particular method of accessing a route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter, in the sense that it will work. However usually, you would like to have several functions doing different things like. POST to /foo, means that you add an element, GET to /foo means that you retrieve the element(s) and DELETE to /foo means that you delete an element.

Comment: Is this a common convention?  POST is used for INSERT operations, and GET is for SELECT operations?

Comment: Well, according to the standards for HTTP methods, one uses. POST to insert a new object, GET to select one, PUT to replace an entire existing one, DELETE to remove it, PATCH to partially update it. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html. I believe PATCH was introduced as a part of REST, as a method to only update the edited properties, and not the entire object.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify a `methods` argument to `app.route()`, then the default is to only accept `GET` and `HEAD` requests <sup>(*)</sup>.

You only need to explicitly set `methods` if you need to accept *other HTTP methods*, such as `POST`, otherwise Flask will respond with a [*405 Method Not Allowed* HTTP response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) when a client uses a HTTP method you didn't list, and your route function is simply not called.

So if your route *should* handle both `GET` and `POST` requests, but you forgot to add `methods=['GET', 'POST']` to `@route()`, then you have a bug as `POST` requests result in a 405 response instead of your route handling the request.

In your case, however, you should *not* use `methods=['GET', 'POST']`, and instead let clients that try to use POST anyway know your route doesn't handle that method. Better to be explicit about the error than let it silently pass.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> `HEAD` is added whenever you use register a route that handles `GET`, and in case of a `HEAD` request, your route is called and only the headers are then served to the client. Flask automatically handles [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) for you, the route is not called in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As always, the answer is: it depends.

If you don't provide "methods" arguments, then Flask assumes the HTTP method is GET (and also accepts HEAD).  So long as that assumption is valid, your code will work just fine.

If, however, your web page is communicated as a POST method (or DELETE, etc.), Flask will fail and complain that the POST (or DELETE, etc.) request is not allowed.

Think of this requirement as a redundancy check.  Flask could have been written to adapt to whatever method is used in the HTTP request.  Instead, Flask insists that you specify the method as a signal that the form of communication is intentional.  This requirement makes the Flask implementation a little simpler at the cost of imposing the responsibility of coordinating the client-server interface on the programmer.

Comment: Is it a common convention that POST is used for DELETE operations, and GET is used for other operations?  In another response above, he implied  POST is used for INSERT operations, and GET is for SELECT operations?

Comment: There are HTTP purists that are careful to specify HEAD, GET, POST, DELETE, UPDATE, etc. methods specifically.  Flask accommodates all of those options.  And if you specify UPDATE as your HTTP method, you need to include "UPDATE" in your list of Flask methods.  You are correct, however, that it is common just to use POST to handle all "change" operations.